# I have meta sites in my community list, but they don't show up in the Android app

Tags: bug, android-app, communities-list

I have two child metas in my community list. In the web interface, they show up (obviously). They also show up in the iOS app. However, they are not in my community list on the Android app.

I will edit in screenshots shortly.

Update: that's odd - all of a sudden they appeared!

Comment: Please post the device. For those of us in the alpha, there are two versions of the app: one for phone and one for tablet.

Comment: I'm using the published version, not the beta for tablets. But i'm on a tablet anyways.

Comment: Actually, that is a better way to differentiate. The published version is the same on all devices, as I understand it.

Comment: In the menu that slides out with a swipe from the left, can you tap `YOUR SITES` to bring up a menu? (I did this on my phone, which I believe is still the same as the published version, but I'm not sure).

Comment: Most possible cause: caching. It's always caching.